# How to not display website content on larger screen

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to not display website content on screen sizes larger than 1600px. For larger screen sizes I would like to show only some image showing some message. How can I do that?

Comment: The PHP and HTML know nothing about screen size. You should look for CSS or JavaScript.

Comment: How do you intend to get the screen size of the client? That is not part of the HTTP request.

Comment: You should research media queries.

Comment: the screen in fount of me is at 1920 1080 why would you "block" the web site from me ? This site is designed for X x Y is very 90's a properly designed modern site can handle any size

Answer (score 1):

First seriously ask yourself why, I'm sure there's a good reason in your use case, but be sure, then:

Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) and display values:

```
@media (max-width: 1600px) {
    /* site styles in here */
    .big-image {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1601px) {
    .page-container {
        display: none;
    }
    .big-image {
        display: block;
        /* more image styles here */
    }
}
```

Here `.page-container` has everything you want to hide in it. `.big-image` is for your image. The display properties are applied depending on the size of the viewport.